# Bs4 and requests Python

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I was trying to make a pokedex (https://replit.com/@Yoplayer1py/Gui-Pokedex) and I wanted to get the pokemon's description from [https://www.pokemon.com/us/pokedex/{__pokename__}](https://www.pokemon.com/us/pokedex/%7B__pokename__%7D) Here **pokename** means the name of the pokemon. for example: https://www.pokemon.com/us/pokedex/unown

There is a  tag contains the description and the p tag's class is : version-xactive.

When i print the description i get nothing or sometimes i get None.

here's the code:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# Assign URL
url = "https://www.pokemon.com/us/pokedex/"+text_id_name.get(1.0, "end-1c")
    
# Fetch raw HTML content
html_content = requests.get(url).text
    
# Now that the content is ready, iterate 
# through the content using BeautifulSoup:
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_content, "html.parser")
    
# similarly to get all the occurences of a given tag
print(soup.find('p', attrs={'class': 'version-xactive'}).text)
```

The `text_id_name.get(1.0, "end-1c")` is from tkinter text input.

it shows that :

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1883, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "main.py", line 57, in load_pokemon
    print(soup.find('p', attrs={'class': 'version-xactive'}).text)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'
```

Thanks in advance !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the classes, multiple, of the description are `version-x active` (at least for [Unown](https://www.pokemon.com/us/pokedex/unown)). That is why `soup.find('p', attrs={'class': 'version-xactive'}` is not finding the element, thereby returning `None` (hence why you are getting the error).

Adding a space will fix your problem: `print(soup.find('p', attrs={'class': 'version-xactive'}).text)`. Just to note: if there are multiple `p` elements with the same classes, so `find` method might not return the element you want.

Adding a null check will also prevent the error from occurring:

```
description = soup.find('p', attrs={'class': 'version-x active'})
if description:
    print(desription.text)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should probably separate out your calls so you can do a safety check and a type check.

Replace

```
print(soup.find('p', attrs={'class': 'version-xactive'}).text)
```

with

```
tags = soup.find('p', attrs={'class': 'version-xactive'})
print("Tags:", tags)
if(type(tags) != NoneType):
    print(tags.text)
```

That should give you more information at least. It might still break on `tags.text`. If it does, put the printout from `print("Tags:", tags)` up so we can see what the data looks like.